# How to prevent race condition when updating session value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

In my Controller, I need to check if a session has expired, and if so, update the value:

```
public function some_method(Request $request)
{
    // get previous last activity
    $session_last_activity = session('session_last_activity');
    // update last activity to now
    session(['session_last_activity'] => now());

    if ($session_expiry_date < now()->subMinutes(10)) {
        $some_value = Str::random(30);
        session(['some_value' => $some_value]);
    } else {
        $some_value = session('some_value');
    }


    // proceed to update or create some record on the DB
}
```

The problem occurs when the session is expired, and there are quick multiple requests to the same page. Then, for those immediate requests, each request creates a new random string and updates the session.

So the last request will have the last session value, however, by that time, the database created multiple records because, for each of these requests, the session expired for a moment.

For example, a user clicks `example.com/page1` twice quickly while the session was expired. Now there are 2 requests that read the session as expired, set a new key, and create 2 records with 2 different keys, even though there was supposed to be only one.

How can I prevent that without using cache, or not on the DB side (i.e. with DB locks), but rather on the code side?

Comment: 100% cache, [atomic locks](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#atomic-locks), there is no other way. Explain why you cannot use cache

Comment: Windows Server with no Docker/Linux VM (yet, but working on it) :/

Comment: @Stackerito You can install windows subsystem for linux. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

Comment: Thank you, this is what I might do (but only for development), problem is I don't want to use it on production server, but hopefully by that time I will be able to use a Linux VM/Docker.

Comment: @Stackerito pardon my ignorance, I have nearly no idea about windows server, what is the issue? Can't you install it on Windows Server? What about Azure? AWS and pay for small cache?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I was wrong, there is the `file` Cache driver!

Comment: @matiaslauriti my bad, `file` driver doesn't have atomic locks

Comment: @Stackerito as I said before... why can't you install redis on Windows Server? Again, you can use `database` as cache, not recommended but for this should be okay

Comment: You are right, I will try to add the database driver together with the file. But, how can I specify the database driver on the route I want to block?, Assuming the endpoint is `/api` for example, if the default driver would be `file`?

Answer (score 1):

***Answer update based on your question update***:

One approach is to use a flag stored in the session itself to indicate whether a request is already in the process of updating the session.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function some_method(Request $request)
{
    $session_expiry_date = session('session_expiry_date');

    if ($session_expiry_date < now()) {
        $lockKey = 'session_update_lock';
        
        // Check if the session update lock flag is set
        if (!Session::has($lockKey)) {
            // Set the lock flag to prevent other requests from updating the session
            Session::put($lockKey, true);
            
            $some_value = Str::random(30);
            
            // Update the session with the new value
            session(['some_value' => $some_value]);
            
            // Proceed to update or create the record on the DB
            // ...
            
            // Clear the lock flag to allow other requests to update the session
            Session::forget($lockKey);
        } else {
            // Another request is already updating the session, so retrieve the value
            $some_value = session('some_value');
        }
    } else {
        $some_value = session('some_value');
    }

    // Proceed with the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I don't have cache T_T. Also I added an example

Comment: @Stackerito it's a built-in laravel feature, you can use it by calling it in top of your class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;`

Comment: Yes but I haven't configured it as I can't use Redis/Memcached on this system and I do not want to use the databsase driver

Comment: thank you, but is there a way to stop that on the session side and not the DB?

Comment: check again the answer

Comment: Thank you, but isn't it the same, just passed to another session flag? Because if it will happen quickly, it will also see both flags as "false"?

Comment: My bad, I can use cache with `file` driver. You can change back to your solution with Cache and I can try it, sorry

Comment: Update: My bad, I don't think `file` driver would work because it doesn't support atomic locks

Answer (score 0):

To lock the session, you can use [`block`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#session-blocking) on your route. The session locking will be acquired for this request whenever many simultaneous requests are incoming.

So, if this request is for say `example.com/page1`, then the snippet would be:

```
Route::get('/page1', function () {
    // your code
})->block(5, 5);
```

However, for this to be in effect, you must be using a cache driver that supports atomic locks. Quoting from the docs:

> To utilize session blocking, your application must be using a cache
> driver that supports atomic locks. Currently, those cache drivers
> include the memcached, dynamodb, redis, and database drivers. In
> addition, you may not use the cookie session driver.

Comment: thank you, the problem is for this system I can't use Cache. How bad would that be to use `usleep` to make it sleep for a few microseconds?

Comment: @Stackerito why can't you use cache? You can use `database` driver for it (just for this)

Comment: @Stackerito `usleep` will just delay the response for the current request. It will not control the queue of the incoming requests

Comment: @nice_dev thank you, so I might use the database driver only to limit api calls. But, now that I'll have 2 drivers, one being the default file driver, how can I specify that I want to use the database driver for the `block`method on the route?

Comment: @Stackerito Route based drivers are bad system designs. Try redis.

Comment: The problem is I can't use redis right now so I have to use something else temporarily until I can. It would only be for this route. Maybe I can use the database driver in a different manner to throttle it?

Comment: @Stackerito Go with any driver you wish to use that supports `block`. I am afraid I can't participate any further.